# limitation add node primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, treenode

i have this:

```
 public void addView(){
        vi.setName_view("View");

        System.out.println(selectedNode.getParent().getData());
         TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode(new TreeNodeType().getVIEW_TYPE(),vi.getName_view()+""+v++, selectedNode);

        FacesContext context= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "View "+vi.getName_view()+" Added to "+"Cube "+cub.getName_cube(), ""));
    }
```

i wanna add just one Node of this type in the some parent node so i should put a test if under this node parent i have more then one `View` Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the question? What I understood was that you want to add a child Node of the same type as a parent programatically?

Comment: yes but the user can add just one type of VIEW_TYPE() if he try to add other one a error msg appear

Comment: The selected node (the one that will have a child) can only have at most ONLY ONE child? Is that it?

Comment: yes for each parent i should have just one child of typeView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code it's worked for me:

```
public void changeName(){

        String res =selectedNode.getData().toString();

    voila =root.getChildren().get(0);
        if(selectedNode.getData().toString() !=null){
            res=cubMang.cubUpdate.getName_cube();

            selectedNode= new DefaultTreeNode(new TreeNodeType().getCUBE_TYPE(),res, voila);

        TreeNode test= voila.getChildren().get(0);
        selectedNode.getParent().getChildren().remove(voila.getChildren().lastIndexOf(selectedNode)-1);

    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it's will work for you :

```
   public void addView(){

        vi.setName_view("View");
        //System.out.println(selectedNode.getRowKey()); 
        //System.out.println(selectedNode.getChildCount());
    int i=0;
         TreeNode node0;
            List<TreeNode> testNode=selectedNode.getParent().getChildren();

            for ( i= 0;i<testNode.size();i++){
                FacesContext context= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

                System.out.println(testNode.get(i).getChildren());
                if(testNode.get(i).getChildren().isEmpty() || testaddView == false  ){
                    node0 = new DefaultTreeNode(new TreeNodeType().getVIEW_TYPE(),vi.getName_view()+""+v++, selectedNode);

                    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, vi.getName_view()+" Added to "+cub.getName_cube(), "")); 
             testaddView = true;
             }

                else{
                            FacesContext contexte= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                            contexte.addMessage("Warrning", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warnning", "You can't add other View To this Cube")); 

                        }

            }

    }
```